# Problem with SetWindowsHookEx Function C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I am developing an application that needs to handle all messages sent by the OS to any application.

The code works fine for WH_KEYBOARD_LL only, but fails with WH_GETMESSAGE or WH_CALLWNDPROC

```
class Program
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WH_GETMESSAGE = 3;
    private const int WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static HookProc _proc = new HookProc(HookCallback);
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("date.txt");
        tw.Write(DateTime.Now);
        tw.Close();

        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }
    private static IntPtr SetHook(HookProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC , proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr HookProc(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        // This method is never called

        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, code, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
         HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
       IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

}

Edit:

I think the problem is with the .NET Frame work

Global hooks are not supported in the .NET Framework
Except for the WH_KEYBOARD_LL low-level hook and the WH_MOUSE_LL low-level hook, you cannot implement global hooks in the Microsoft .NET Framework.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804

Answer (score 1):

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318804, you can't do global hooks in .NET (except for WH_KEYBOARD_LL).  See the information at the end of that article.

Answer (score 0):

why are you passing `curModule.ModuleName` into the winapi ?